# Why is Github not picking up my contributions once I've connected my application to Netlify?

Tags: github, netlify

I've deployed an app on Netlify through continuous deployment by linking a single Github repo. I had previously been making commits to the project locally, and my contributions were being tracked for this repo. However, now that I've linked the repo to Netlify, it seems no commits or contributions I make are picked up by Github. The commits can still be seen in the Github repo and commits are updated, but the contributions no longer are tracked despite them working previously.

For some context I've checked the Github help page on contributions:

https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile

And cannot see what rule I've violated; I'm working on this on my own, it's a standalone repo, etc etc. considering they were being tracked before for the same repo, I'm confused as to what has changed now that Netlify has been integrated.

Any help/guidance appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it had nothing to do with Netlify, but my work Mac did not have me globally installed as the commit author with my email. After that, all previous authors were wrong as being my local computer email.

To get around this I followed this tutorial to replace all previous commits with the correct author: [How do I change the author and committer name/email for multiple commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59587820/13135172)